# how to compare asp.net radio button list values

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to fix a search tool for work. This is the first time I have encountered ASP.NET. The current search tool has a radio Button list with three options of how to search our local directory. However the person that worked on this project before me did not finish the code and has since quit. The radio buttons as they are not do not affect the search query as I have noticed that no matter what option you pick the query is the same.

This is my attempt to rewrite the search function to incorporate the three radio button options. However when I incorporate this function into the rest of the code the page does not render at all and I am not getting the error. I dont think I made an error in the query strings because I took the original one and made variations of it by omitting Contains statements. I'm assuming the error comes from my if statements or how I am trying to compare the asp.net RadioButtonList ListItem values.

```
protected void btnclick_WorkspaceSearch(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string strSearchTerm=tbSearch.Text.Trim() 

    if (rblSearchOption.SelectedValue == "all"){
        // Find the search term in either a file name or file content
        string indexQuery = "SELECT docauthor,doctitle, FileName, Path, Write, Size, Rank";
        indexQuery += "FROM " + "Workspace" + "..SCOPE() WHERE ";
        indexQuery += "CONTAINS(FileName, '\"" + strSearchTerm + "\"') ";
        indexQuery += "OR CONTAINS(Contents, '\"" + strSearchTerm + "\"') ";
        indexQuery += "ORDER BY Rank DESC";
    }
    if (rblSearchOption.SelectedValue=="names"){
        // Find the search term in a file name 
        string indexQuery = "SELECT docauthor,doctitle, FileName, Path, Write, Size, Rank";
        indexQuery += "FROM " + "Workspace" + "..SCOPE() WHERE ";
        indexQuery += "CONTAINS(FileName, '\"" + strSearchTerm + "\"') ";
        indexQuery += "ORDER BY Rank DESC";
    }
    if (rblSearchOption.SelectedValue =="contents") {
        // Find the search term in a file's content
        string indexQuery = "SELECT docauthor,doctitle, FileName, Path, Write, Size, Rank";
        indexQuery += "FROM " + "Workspace" + "..SCOPE() WHERE ";
        indexQuery += "CONTAINS(FileName, '\"" + strSearchTerm + "\"') ";
        indexQuery += "ORDER BY Rank DESC";
    }
    searchIndex(indexQuery);
    lit_strQueryString.Text = indexQuery;
}
```

Comment: It probably isn't the main problem, but you need a space after the word Rank in your list of fields to be selected. A space between Rank and FROM.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you pasted the concatenated SQL string. Also, will all due respect, for this messy code I would definitely create a unit test, maybe one for each input (and use parameterized queries, of course).

Comment: Where is `indexQuery` defined when you right-click `searchIndex(indexQuery);` and say "Navigate to definition"?  The three `indexQuery` variables are locally scoped inside the `if` statements and so wouldn't be usable in the outer scope (the entire method).  Also you're missing a `;` at the end of the first line.  Did you copy/paste this from your actual working code-base?

Comment: Also, when concatenating a large string with a few variables, it can sometimes be easier to read and comprehend using a multi-line string `@" ... "` and `string.Format` to insert the variable values (like a `printf`).

Comment: This is also not the main problem, but your third option returns the same indexQuery as your second option. Don't you want it to say "CONTAINS(Contents,......"?

Comment: When you run this through the debugger, what is the value of indexQuery in the line: searchIndex(indexQuery);? And does searchIndex() return a value? Where does the result of the query get posted to your page?

Comment: The only problem with the original code was that the person that wrote it did not yet change the search function to incorporate the filename only and file content only search options. The code as it appears. I know the multiple concats are annoying but thats how it was in the orignal working code. and yes I realize I have some syntax errors now. I had fixed them in my test code previously. I cannot use a debugger for this code because I don't have install permissions on the server I am working on and I am coding in notepad Which is very irritating but my bosses refuse to comprehend that.

Comment: OK - is lit_strQueryString a control on your aspx page? If so, does it show a value? Do you have access to the code that defines searchIndex()? If so, does it return something other than void? Can you assign what searchIndex() returns to a variable and assign that variable to a control on your page, just to check what it's returning?

Comment: Also, make sure your 3 queries actually return data. You may just be displaying null data on your page

Comment: I do not have access to lit_strQueryString but searchIndex() calls the db query with the query string. gets the result table from the database and moves it to a Dataview and binds the dataview to a datagrid.

Comment: I found lit_strqueryString it is just the id of asp Literal tags where the query that was performed is diplayed. Im assuming that is just for debugging purposes. Null data is displayed as an empty grid. The problem I am having is that the page does not even render anymore when I try to implement this search function instead of the original which just has the Query with two Contains clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. For those that commented thank you for your input I did make some necessary changes to help correct potential errors. As for the original question to compare listItem values the line that I used was :

```
if (rblSearchOption.SelectedItem.Value =="contents"){
//logic here
}
```

i had tried this before but it did not work. I'm assuming because of the errors pointed out in the comments.

Additional Notes(based on the comments):
 The code above has a missing ; in line1

string index query should be declared and initiated outside of the if statements.

Once again thank you to those who attempted to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found your problem, a bit unrelated but looking at your code I would say it needs some serious refactoring. This code can be simplified by:

1) Using a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx) statement.This will help evaluating the selected value of the radio button list just once unlike your code

2) Using a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to construct the query

3) Removing repetition - the append logic for *names* and *contents* is exactly the same you can remove the repetition by using two case expression and providing one statement to execute.

```
  System.Text.StringBuilder indexQuery = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  indexQuery.Append("SELECT docauthor,doctitle, FileName, Path, Write, Size, Rank FROM Workspace..SCOPE() WHERE ");

    switch(rblSearchOption.SelectedItem.Value)
    {
        case "all":
        indexQuery.AppendFormat("CONTAINS(FileName,'{0}') ",strSearchTerm);
        indexQuery.AppendFormat("OR CONTAINS(Contents,'{0}')",strSearchTerm);
        indexQuery.AppendLine("ORDER BY Rank DESC");
            break;
        case "names":
        case "contents":
        indexQuery.AppendFormat("CONTAINS(FileName,'{0}')",strSearchTerm);
        indexQuery.Append("ORDER BY Rank DESC");
            break;
    }

    searchIndex(indexQuery.ToString());
    lit_strQueryString.Text = indexQuery;
```